# Bit manipulation over flow

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift, byte-shifting

Given the following formula :

```
(((a-b)>>3) + c-d+4)<<2
```

And each variable is a *8 bit register*, need to find a few bits need for results will not be *OVERFLOW* .

I think the answer is `11` .

the biggest number that we can take at `(a-b) + the biggest number in (c-d+4)` .

its bona be grate  if someone can explain .

Comment: Is the question: Given signed integers `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` each in [-128,127], what is the minimum number of bits N required such that neither the *final* result nor any of the *intermediate* results will overflow [-2**(N-1), 2**(N-1)-1], and where `>>` denotes a signed (arithmetic) right shift.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track, we shoud try to make `a-b` and `c-d+4` as big as possible, so we set `a=255`, `b=0`, `c=255`, and `d=0`.

The shift left operator part results in `(((a-b)>>3)=31` (5 bits).

And `c-d+4=259` (need 9 bits here).

`31+259=290`(so here we need 9 bits).

And finally `(290<<2)=1160` we shift left 2 times, and end up needing 11 bits, which could store a value up to 2047.